# Speed up scraping process using python asyncio queue

Tags: python, queue, python-asyncio

I am trying to build a simple scraper which collects company stock symbol list from wikipidea link and then search those symbols in yahoo finance e.g `https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MMM`. To make it more robust and learn python asyncio better I decided to use `asyncio.Queue`. Right now I have working scraper but it is taking 62 seconds for scraping just 15 symbols. Here is my Wikipedia scraper code in which I am yielding the symbols rather storing the whole list in the memory:
import asyncio

```
from selectolax.lexbor import LexborHTMLParser
import httpx


class WikiWorker:
    def __init__(self):
        self._url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies"

    @staticmethod
    def _parse_company_symbols(page_html):
        html = LexborHTMLParser(page_html)
        table = html.css_first("table#constituents")
        for td in table.css("tr")[1:15]:
            symbol = td.css_first("td").text(strip=True)
            yield symbol

    def get_sp_500_companies(self):
        response = httpx.get(self._url)
        html = response.text
        yield from self._parse_company_symbols(html)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    wikiWorker = WikiWorker()
    asyncio.run(wikiWorker.get_sp_500_companies())
```

and here is my yahoo finance scraper in which I am getting the stock price and putting it in the queue:

```
import asyncio
from selectolax.lexbor import LexborHTMLParser
import httpx


class YahooFinancePriceScheduler:
    def __init__(self, input_queue: asyncio.Queue, **kwargs):
        self._input_queue = input_queue

    async def run(self):
        while True:
            val = await self._input_queue.get()
            print(val)
            yahooFinanceWorker = YahooFinanceWorker(symbol=val)
            price = yahooFinanceWorker.get_price()
            print(price)
            self._input_queue.task_done()


class YahooFinanceWorker:
    def __init__(self, symbol, **kwargs):
        self._symbol = symbol
        base_url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"
        self._url = f"{base_url}{self._symbol}"

    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:120.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/120.0"
    }

    def get_price(self):
        print(self._url)
        response = httpx.get(self._url, headers=self.headers, follow_redirects=True)
        html = LexborHTMLParser(response.text)
        try:
            price = float(
                html.css_first('[data-test="qsp-price"]')
                .text(strip=True)
                .replace(",", "")
            )
            return price
        except AttributeError:
            return None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    yfps = YahooFinancePriceScheduler("MMM")
    yfps.run()
```

and here is scraper entry point:

```
import asyncio
import time
from workers.wikiWorker import WikiWorker
from workers.yahooFinanceWorker import YahooFinancePriceScheduler


NUM_WORKERS = 5
SYMBOL_QUEUE_MAX_SIZE = 100


async def main():
    symbol_queue = asyncio.Queue()
    tasks = []
    

    wikiWorker = WikiWorker()
    scraper_start_time = time.time()
    for _ in range(NUM_WORKERS):
        yahooFinancePriceScheduler = YahooFinancePriceScheduler(
            input_queue=symbol_queue
        )

        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(yahooFinancePriceScheduler.run()))

    for symbol in wikiWorker.get_sp_500_companies():
        await symbol_queue.put(symbol)
    

    
    await symbol_queue.join()

    for task in tasks:
        task.cancel()

    print("Extracting time took:", round(time.time() - scraper_start_time, 1))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Is there anything I can do to speed things up here?

Comment: The [yfinance](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance) library might be useful

Comment: I am just using this scenerio from a learning aspect teaching myself asyncio queues actually.

Comment: Main delay is probably caused by the synchronous (blocking) `httpx.get` call in `get_price`. Try the asynchronous API of `httpx` instead.

Comment: Using asynchronous API of  `httpx` did speed up the process. Thanks!